# How to move vs code workspace settings from github.dev to vscode.dev?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vs-code-settings

from github, I have opened **[github.dev](https://github.dev)** which load vs code and there are so many folders so added few settings there which are in .vscode/settings.json file

and there are **[vscode.dev](https://vscode.dev)** is also ,

open the same repository on **vscode.dev** , this is also a new instance of vs code web and I need the same settings saved on **github.dev** settings, so one way is to copy from there and paste it here.

or so use **sync settings** or **Custom Profile** feature of vs code or any github  related extension will be helpful here ?

so give it a try to *Custom Profile* feature which introduced recently by vs code.

so, first need to export profile from **github.dev**

go to *Settings --> Profiles --> Export Profile...*

[image: export profile]

while exporting it ask for the location where to export the profile, on vs code desktop app, usually it ask for a folder on system and it export as **.profile**

but here we are on web instance of vs code, so it asked for gist and save the gist ; below is the link of gist

[vs code profile gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/xkeshav/0d1cec6aaa3e03dfb88a7b19ced5effe/raw/9c888d0214f430cedcd12bc4f55f51922208c102/Doc%2520Writer)

now on **vscode.dev** side, we need to import this profile using

*Settings-->Profiles > Import Profile...*

but there is no feature to import from online resouces but it is asking to select file *Create from profile template file*, this is looking for a file with **.profile** extension, within the same workspace.

so my request is to add feature to paste profile gist while import profile.

or is there any way to do it ?

and intrestingly that gist  which was created has so many metadata and do not store as a `.profile` but a gist with content.

so this is also a feature request while exporting file in gist, store it as *.profile* in gist

[image: vvs code settings--> Profiles -->Import Profile]